# Regexp to start matching after a specific character

Tags: regex

In `someXstring` it's easy to find everything after and including 'X'.

What I need is to find everything after, but EXCLUDING 'X'.

... just to match `string` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a lookbehind assertion.

```
(?<=X)\w+
```

If you regex engine doesn't support lookbehind assertions, you can work around that using capturing groups.

```
X(\w+)
```

In the above regex, `string` would be accessed referencing `\1`.

NOTE: this uses `\w` to capture word characters. If you literally mean that you want to capture *everything* then use the dot, `.`, metacharacter instead...

```
(?<=X).+$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lookbehind` if available

```
(?<=X).*$
```

if not you can use groups.Grab group `1`.

```
X(.*$)
```